# Read array 2D and output as table C#

Tags: c#

I am new at programming in C# and I'm trying to display to whole content of a matrix in the format of a table, however what I got so far is to read the enum and read one line from the matrix. Instead I need to read multiple lines from the matrix and output as a table.

when I run the program I get to insert data twice in row and the output should've been this data inside a table, but only one line is being shown.
Here's the code:

```
static int getInsertIndex(string[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[j, 0])) return j;
            }

            return -1;
        }
        private static void InsertData<T>(string[,] matrix)
        {

            // int newId = generateId(ref id);
            int n = getInsertIndex(matrix), id = 1;

            matrix[n, 0] = Convert.ToString(id++);
            int x = matrix.GetLength(1) - 1;
            matrix[n, x] = "true";

            for (var j = 1; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write($"\nInsert {GetHeader<T>(j)}: ");
                    matrix[0, j] = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matrix[0, j]));
            }
        }

        private static void ListData<T>(string[,] matrix)
        {
            var array = new string[matrix.GetUpperBound(1)];

            for (var l = 0; l < matrix.GetLength(0); l++)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = matrix[0, i];
                }
            }

            PrintRow(array);
            PrintLine();
        }

        private static string GetHeader<T>(int i) => Enum.GetName(typeof(T), i);

        private static void ShowHeader<T>(string[,] matrix)
        {
            var array = new string[matrix.GetUpperBound(1)];

            for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = GetHeader<T>(i);
            }

            PrintLine();
            PrintRow(array);
            PrintLine();
        }

        private static void PrintLine()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', Console.WindowWidth - 1));
        }

        private static void PrintRow(IReadOnlyCollection<string> columns)
        {
            var width = (Console.WindowWidth - 1 - columns.Count) / columns.Count;
            var row = columns.Aggregate("|", (current, column) => current + AlignCentre(column, width) + "|");
            Console.WriteLine(row);
        }

        static string AlignCentre(string text, int width)
        {
            text = text.Length > width ? text.Substring(0, width - 3) + "..." : text;

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
                ? new string(' ', width)
                : text.PadRight(width - (width - text.Length) / 2).PadLeft(width);
        }

        enum ClientHeader { Id, Name, Surname, Addres, CodPostal, Telephone, Email, State };

        private static void Main()
        {
            var client = new string[4, 7];
            InsertData<ClientHeader>(client);

            Console.Clear();
            InsertData<ClientHeader>(client);

            ShowHeader<ClientHeader>(client);
            ListData<ClientHeader>(client);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:

1) In the `InsertData()` function, you want to update the `n` th row.

Replace

```
matrix[0, j] = Console.ReadLine();
```

by

```
matrix[n, j] = Console.ReadLine();
```

2) In the `ListData()` function you want to show each row, so you need to move the array variable into the first `for` loop. Replace `array[i] = matrix[0, i]` with `array[i] = matrix[l, i]` because you are displaying the `l` th row.

```
private static void ListData<T>(string[,] matrix)
{
    for (var l = 0; l < matrix.GetLength(0); l++)
    {
        var array = new string[matrix.GetUpperBound(1)];

        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = matrix[l, i];
        }

        PrintRow(array);
    }

    PrintLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>() {
                new List<string>() { "Name", "Age", "Weight"},
                new List<string>() { "John", "33", "180"},
                new List<string>() { "Mary", "32", "125"},
                new List<string>() { "Harry", "40", "200"}
            };

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    foreach (string col in data[i])
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(col);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(data[i].ToArray());
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is there a way without DataTable??

Comment: You request was for a table.  What other type table do you mean.

Comment: the output has to be a table but I was trying to do from an array 2 D